# What is the Python equivalent of Ruby's fork block?

Tags: python, ruby, fork

With Ruby, a `fork` block can be used to express that

> Statements in this block are only executed in the child process and will be skipped over by the parent process.

Is there something similar in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Python, but I think you do it just like you do it in C, by checking the return value of `fork()`:

```
child_pid = os.fork()
if child_pid == 0:
    print "This is the child."
    sys.exit(0)
print "This is the parent."
```

Comment: In this way, the child process will also prints "This is the parent.". How can I make sure anything outside the "fork block" is not executed in child *processes*.

Comment: No, it's the parent that prints "This is the parent". The child calls `sys.exit(0)` before it gets to that line.  It is by exiting the child at the end of the block that you ensure the child executes nothing but the block.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have some code executed in child processes, use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module. Here's an example from documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This example shows how function **f** can be executed inside child process.